# VBA 1004 error on selecting "No" or "Cancel" when asked to replace file during SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA where the user fills out a template, then saves as .XLSM and PDF.

The .XLSM saves as the entire workbook, but the PDF is only 2 worksheets. Both files are named after a variable cell in the workbook and a file location is suggested, but can be changed by the user.

Everything works until the user is warned that they are overwriting an existing file. If they select "no" or "cancel," then they get an error. Ideally, I would like for the sub to just exit and neither the PDF or .XLSM is saved. I have tried On Error, but cannot get the whole thing to work. Other solutions seem to take away some functionality (variable file name, different sheets printing/saving, initial file location, etc.).

Below is my code if anyone can help:

```
Sub SaveToPDF2()

Dim strFilename     As String
Dim rngRange        As Range
Dim fileSave As FileDialog
Set fileSave = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)


'Considering Sheet1 to be where you need to pick file name
Set rngRange = Worksheets("template").Range("b3")

'Create File name with dateStamp
strFilename = rngRange.Value & ".process." & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy")

With fileSave
' Your default save location here
    .InitialFileName = "U:\221 Released Drawings\" & strFilename

    If .Show = -1 Then

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=strFilename & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("process", "signoff")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
filename:=strFilename _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Else: Exit Sub


    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the next code line, just before `With fileSave`:

```
If Dir(strFilename & ".xlsm") <> "" then Exit Sub
```

If such a file already exists, the code is exited on the above inserted line...

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and still got a 1004 run-time error.